# from one html file to another in loop html/jquery/js/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

maybe its easy, but I'm really beginner in front end.
Right now I've got:

- 1 main html file(index.html)
- 1 javascript file(something.js)
- 2nd html file(something.html)

Main html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/something.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid well-lg">
    <div id="targetInformation">

    </div>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

2nd html:

```
<div class=" col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                Some title
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>info1</p>
            <p>info2</p>
            <p>info3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to:
create a loop in js/jquery/ajax to load 6 times what is inside 2nd html to a first html.
One thing I know is that I need to use $.get().
Any ideas how my js should look like, and how to use js in a div?
Thanks :)
Tried to find a solution, but didnt found, sorry for bothering

ps. I didnt send you my something.js, because its empty, really got no idea how to start.

Comment: You want to load the same file 6 times? Why not load it once and copy it? You're correct that `$.get()` would help you with this. the documentation would have been the next logical step: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: I mean I want to load this 6 times, not a file ofc :)

Comment: That still doesn't make any sense I'm afraid

Comment: actually I can copy it like u said. Thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This -

```
$(function () {
            $.get("something.html", function (data) {
              for(let i =0; i<6; i++)
                 {
                    $("#targetInformation").append(data);
                 }

            });
        });
```